# logstash convert date from MMM dd YYYY to mm dd YYYY?

Tags: date, datetime, elasticsearch, logstash

i have a date format like "Apr 17 09:32:01" but i want to get the month in number ... 
Is it possible to convert it using logstash? 
I tried with date filter but it doesnt seem to be able to convert date from a format to another.

i looked for a date conversion like %{mydate:+dd-mm-yyyy} but it doesnt work

it's annoying because i got 2 differents logs sources for the same group (i want them into the same index) and i'm using the date into my index name in Elasticsearch. Without the conversion i have 2 different index ... (one like myindex-20-05-2015, the other like myindex-20-may-2015)

do you have any clue ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the date{} filter to replace @timestamp with the event's timestamp and then the data will go into the correct index.

```
date {
  match => [ 'myField', "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
}
```